# Angular2 Observable Rxjs how to call private function

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

Ok, I am new to RxJs, got introduced today.. so this is a totally newbie question.

My use case is to extract XML RSS feed and convert them to JSON feed.

I have a FeedService which has the following

```
getFeedContent(url: string) : Observable<Feed> {
    return this.http.get(url)
        .map(this.extractFeeds)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}

private extractFeeds(res: Response) {
    let content = res.text;
    let feed = this.extractItems(content);
    return feed ;
}
```

The extract Items is a regular function which takens in a content and does XML parsing to build the json object. There are multiple other methods

Here is the code

```
private extractItems(content) : Feed {
    console.log(content);
    let f = this.getFeedInfo(content);
    return {
        status: "ok",
        feed : f ,
        items: this.getItems(content.toString(), 'item')
                   .concat(this.getItems(content.toString(), 'entry'))
    }
}
```

I am getting this error when I run this code :

> feed.service.ts:144 this.extractItems is not a function

I might be mixing Observables with regular function calls and I need help. 
How to call extractItems with the XML content as an input.

Thanks,

Comment: If you could get a plunker with what you have showing the same error I could help you debug better. even if the feed is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue stems from the 'this' context. When trying to use this.extractItems() the context of 'this' is within the observable not the class.

Try something like this:

```
let extractFeeds = (res: Response) => {
    let content = res.text;
    let feed = this.extractItems(content);
    return feed;
}
```

You may need to import of from rxjs as well.

By using the arrow notation you will not have a 'this' context for the observable and calling methods within the class will work.

Comment: No, exact same error message " this.extractItems is not a function"

Comment: I even changed the extractFeeds function signature to   private extractFeeds(res: Response) : Observable<Feed> ... and it didn't help

Comment: @RajeshJain I made an update to the code give that a shot.

Comment: @rjustin, while the updated code in your answer is correct the actual reason for the error in question is different. :) See my answer.

Comment: @AlexanderLeonov The reason I update was regarding the 'this' context I just didnt want to overwhelm if something else was at play.  I am sure he will appreciate your descriptive answer although you may want to include the duplicate post it came from as well.

Comment: @rjustin, you should have mentioned it. Also, your answer is not correct since Observable.map() does expect mapping function to return plain value and not an Observable, if you try to do it that way then flatMap() must be used instead, otherwise you'll get an Observable in your subscription instead of the value it should have emitted. Using your code original error will go away, that's true, but you do not describe why.

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is how `this` is handled by different pieces of this puzzle. Typescript compiler will produce following javascript:

```
YourComponent.prototype.getFeedContent = function (url) {
    return this.http.get(url)
        .map(this.extractFeeds)
        .catch(this.handleError);
};
YourComponent.prototype.extractFeeds = function (res) {
    var content = res.text;
    var feed = this.extractItems(content);
    return feed;
};
YourComponent.prototype.extractItems = function (content) {
    console.log(content);
    var f = this.getFeedInfo(content);
    return {
        status: 'ok',
        feed: f,
        items: this.getItems(content.toString(), 'item')
            .concat(this.getItems(content.toString(), 'entry'))
    };
};
```

Now, the main caveat with this code is when `.map()` operator calls `extractFeeds()` function it does that in the context of the ***Observable*** returned by the `this.http.get()` call, **not in the context of your component**. So, inside `extractFeeds()` function `this` points to that Observable, and trying to call `this.extractItems()` obviously fails because there's no such method on the Observable.

So, fixing it is actually pretty simple. All you need to do is to change extractFeeds() declaration as follows:

```
getFeedContent(url: string): Observable<Feed> {
    return this.http.get(url)
        .map(this.extractFeeds)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}

private extractFeeds = (res: Response) => { // <-- using arrow syntax
    let content = res.text;
    let feed = this.extractItems(content);
    return feed ;
}

private extractItems(content) : Feed {
    console.log(content);
    let f = this.getFeedInfo(content);
    return {
        status: "ok",
        feed : f ,
        items: this.getItems(content.toString(), 'item')
                   .concat(this.getItems(content.toString(), 'entry'))
    }
}
```

This time Typescript compiler produces the following code:

```
var YourComponent = (function () {
    function YourComponent(http) {
        var _this = this;
        this.http = http;
        this.extractFeeds = function (res) { // this is how it is defined now in JS
            var content = res.text;
            var feed = _this.extractItems(content);
            return feed;
        };
    }
    // ... rest declarations skipped
    return YourComponent;
}());
```

See what TSC did here? It preserved reference to your component into `_this` variable and used it for calling `extractItems()` function inside `extractFeeds()`. This way `this` pointer in Typescript version of your code will **always** point to your component instance inside `extractFeeds()` function regardless of where `this` points in real javascript code.

Same goes to all other functions that are called the same way, for example, handleError in your code.

You can find highly detailed explanation of `this` problem in Typescript [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/'this'-in-TypeScript).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. It worked, albeit a minor adjustment , I had to provide a encodingHint to the res.text    let content =  res.text("iso-8859");

Comment: @RajeshJain, glad I could help. Please accept answer if it worked. And good luck in further Typescript+Angular4 learning! :)